# Trigger a dynamic SQL Server stored procedure to run every day

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures

I have a dynamic stored procedure which runs in SSMS. Is it possible to convert this proc into a function so when ever I do

```
exec function stored.proc
```

I can run this from my ETL?

My query as below -

```
create procedure dbo.bear_load
 as
 set nocount on;

 Declare @cols as NVARCHAR(MAX), @query as NVARCHAR(MAX), @Result as NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(FIELD_NAME) 
                from bear_crossjoin
                group by Field_Name, FIELDNUMBER
                order by FIELDNUMBER
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N'  
            from 
            (
                select substring, Field_Name,
                  rn = row_number() over(partition by field_name order by fieldnumber)
                from bear_crossjoin
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(substring)
                for Field_Name in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p ' 
set @Result= ' select ' + @query 
EXEC (@query)
GO


exec dbo.bear_load
```

Any help very much appreciated.

Arun

Comment: Which ETL are you using? At least in SSIS, you can execute a procedure from an OleDB transformation.

Comment: I am using SAP tool. It accepts function i can execute like exec function. But dont know how to convert this to a function or executable stored proc from outside.

Comment: So are you asking how to write a function in SQL Server?

Comment: Well yes that will execute my above query. Sorry i could not find any leads on converting dynamic sql to a function.

Comment: As it happens, you cannot write dynamic SQL in a function in SQL Server. You can write a CLR function (written in C# or VB.NET) for which there are many guides available here and elsewhere on the internet.

Comment: Well can i trigger this to run? Any commands on how to trigger this?

Comment: Or may be load to a view which can be refreshed to generate the results?

Comment: You can't execute dynamic sql in a view. I am not sure why you have this creating a procedure. You could just build the query as dynamic sql and execute it.

Comment: Who says? You are wrong. I modified the stored procedure and created a function and it executed.

Comment: No, you didn't. I don't know what you did, but you did not create a SQL Server function with dynamic SQL in it.

Comment: You can both be right, but be talking about different things. He could have dynamically created a function whose definition is itself static. But I agree with Sean Lange's comment above: why create a function or other object when you can just execute the dynamic SQL directly?

Comment: Thats not possible because i cannot run a dynamic sql query in my ETL. I need a function or a stor proc that executes in SQL Server and brings data to ETL. I have modified the question with what i did.

Comment: @Arun.K: it looks like you are trying to do a pivot. In SSIS, there is a pivot function. Why not do that in your ETL tool instead of trying to do it in dynamic SQL?